# How to iterate several headers in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

When I want to get only the first "Date" header when downloading a file, I can't iterate to choose the first one, 5 "Date" headers come out.

```
Tue, 20 Aug 2019 17:40:36 GMT
Tue, 20 Aug 2019 17:40:37 GMT
Tue, 20 Aug 2019 17:40:37 GMT
Tue, 20 Aug 2019 17:40:37 GMT
Tue, 20 Aug 2019 17:40:37 GMT
```

I have tried with headers.entries (), with for, foreach, without success.

```
await Promise.all([

  await button.click(),
     page.on('response', response => {
          console.log(response._headers['date']);

      })
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this code is doing what you think it is doing:

```
await Promise.all([

  await button.click(),
     page.on('response', response => {
          console.log(response._headers['date']);

      })
  ]);
```

Specifically, `page` in the context of `page.on` is acting as an [event emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter). `page.on` sets up an event handler for a 'response' event, that lasts as long as the `page` object is around.  So every time a 'response' event is fired, that handler function will get activated -- it is not going to get activated only after the `button` is `click()`ed. However, handlers put in place by `page.once` will only fire a single time. The trick is to make sure it happens after you click the button.

I think you want something more like this:

```
async function clickButtonAndGetDate(){
  await button.click();
  page.once('response', response => {
    console.log(response._headers['date']);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with something like this:

```
  var firstdate = null;
  await Promise.all([    
  await button.click(),
     page.on('response', response => {
          firstdate = firstdate == null ? response._headers['date'] : firstdate;
          console.log(response._headers['date']);

      })
  ]);

  console.log("first date", firstdate);
```

If you want to take an action only the first time you can do something more like this

```
  var firstdate = true;
  await Promise.all([    
  await button.click(),
     page.on('response', response => {  
          firstdate && console.log(response._headers['date']); // can replace console.log with your action
          firstdate = false;

      })
  ]);
```